# How to show product tag Woo-Product-Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi members I need some help please below is WordPress Woo-Product-Carouse slider code , I want to add product tags just below the price , please can someone tell me how to achieve it.

```
<div class="product-details-wrap">
                <?php
                if ( $settings['eael_product_carousel_show_title'] ) {
                    echo '<div class="eael-product-title">';
                    if( $should_print_title_clickable ) {
                        echo '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
                    }
                    echo '<' . Helper::eael_validate_html_tag( $settings['eael_product_carousel_title_tag'] ) . '>';
                    if ( empty( $settings['eael_product_carousel_title_length'] ) ) {
                        echo Helper::eael_wp_kses( $product->get_title() );
                    } else {
                        echo implode( " ", array_slice( explode( " ", Helper::eael_wp_kses($product->get_title()) ), 0, $settings['eael_product_carousel_title_length'] ) );
                    }
                    echo '</' . Helper::eael_validate_html_tag( $settings['eael_product_carousel_title_tag'] ) . '>';
                    if( $should_print_title_clickable ) {
                        echo '</a>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>
                <?php if($should_print_price ){
                    echo '<div class="eael-product-price">'.$product->get_price_html().'</div>';
                    
                    echo '<div class="eael-product-tags">'. Helper::eael_validate_html_tag( $settings['eael_product_carousel_title_tag'] ) .'</div>';
                   
                    
                }?>
                <?php if ($should_print_rating) {
                    echo wc_get_rating_html
                    ($product->get_average_rating(), $product->get_rating_count());
                }
                if ( $should_print_excerpt ) {
                    echo '<div class="eael-product-excerpt">';
                    echo '<p>' . wp_trim_words(strip_shortcodes(get_the_excerpt()), $settings['eael_product_carousel_excerpt_length'],
                            $settings['eael_product_carousel_excerpt_expanison_indicator']) . '</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>

            </div>
```

Comment: Hi there, please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can get tags in few ways $product->get_tag_ids(); , using wc_get_product_tag_list() - https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_product_tag_list/  or $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' ); and loop terms .